How to proceed if $f$ is not conservative but almost is
I have been working in this problem about line integrals.
Compute $\int_C \mathbf{f} d\mathbf{r}$ where $\mathbf{f}(x,y,z)=(2x,\cos(y)\cos(z),\sin(y)sin(z))$ and $C$ is the polygonal which links $(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,1,1),(1,1,1),(1,1,0),(1,0,1)$ in this order.
The first thing that came to my mind was using Poincaré lemma to verify if $f$ was conservative: $D_1f_2=0=D_2f_1$, $D_1f_3=0=D_3f_1$ but $D_3f_2=-\cos(y)\sin(z)\neq \cos(y)\sin(z)=D_2f_3$.
I did this so I could use the path independence and reduce the amount of work. But as $f$ seems to not be conservative I assume I just have to parametrize every segment and do the calculus but I have the feeling that I may be missing something since it is "almost" (just by a sign) conservative. The only thing that came to my mind was splitting the original field into $(2x,\cos(y)cos(z),-\sin(y)\sin(z))+(0,0,2\sin(y)\sin(z))$ so the first one is conservative but that does not reduce it too much.
Is there any "trick" on how to proceed in this case or do I have to do it the long way?

The line integral is the sum of five very simple integrals. You probably would have spent less time computing them than writing your question.

Maybe you could say something like $\mathbf{f} = \nabla(x^2+\sin(y)\cos(z)) + 2 \sin(y)\sin(z) \mathbf{k}$, so the integral is equal to the path integral of $2\sin(y)\sin(z)\mathbf{k}$; and the latter could be simplified since any segment in a plane parallel to the $xy$-plane must give an integral of 0.

@TedShifrin That is what I get for not reading the question thoroughly....

Your suggested splitting of the vector field is excellent. Note that you will only have a few easy integrals to evaluate when you do that, aside from the Fundamental Theorem with the conservative part.
